# ios filling in webview with values from objective c using javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

I need to fill a html webview with variables that I have stored in objective C.

I believe that I need to use:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"John", firstName];
```

but not sure what to put there and what my javascript needs to be to implement the passed variables.

here is a little bit of my html to help get an idea:

```
<ul><li><span>First Name:</span> first name needs to go here</li>
  <li><span>Last Name:</span> last name needs to go here</li>
```

**Updated code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"idcard" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *str  = @"John";
    NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFunc('%@')", str];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];


}
```

**Update 2:**
javascript/html:

```
<ul><li><span>Policy Number:</span>        
<script> function myFunc(str)
        {
            document.write(str)  }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using a different js approach and used, hopefully this is helpful to someone.

obj c:

```
NSString *str  = @"John";
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = '%@';", str];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

js:

```
<li><span>Name:</span>   <span id = 'name'>name goes here</span>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a javascript method to add the data to the HTML string. Once you have the function, passing data to it is fairly straight forward,

```
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"methodName([%@])", data]
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

And writing Javascript to place data in HTML string is [easy](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp).

Comment: Is methodName the javascript function name?

Comment: I am getting a blank output in my html. Can you look at my updated code and see where I am going wrong?

Comment: I am sorry, you haven't written a method. Look at this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400230/how-to-update-a-list-of-html-items-based-on-a-list-of-json-data),it uses JQuery nevertheless it should give you an idea.

Comment: I updated my javascript again, now when the view does appear the html goes away and im left with a blank screen with just the variable name I passed. (In this case "John") also changed methodName([%@]) to ('%@) not sure if that affects anything

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the raw HTML string in your code? If so, can you do something like that?

```
UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:webview];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>\
<ul><li><span>First Name:</span> %@</li>\
<li><span>Last Name:</span> %@</li>\
</html>", @"John", @"Smith"];
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

If you want to use JavaScript, here's an example: 
[How to control UIWebView's javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325841/how-to-control-uiwebviews-javascript)

Comment: Although this would and does work it would be a very time consuming to add all the appropriate quotes and such to get it in the correct format.